# is this object on stack or heap?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, heap-memory

In C++/CLI, are the following 2 same or different?

```
System::String ^source("Hello World");

System::String ^source= gcnew System::String("Hello World");
```

Is the first one on stack and second one on heap?
Or are they both on heap?
.Net objects I believe only have references they can't be created on stack unlike C++ allows us. Can someone explain please?

Comment: .NET has both, heap and stack types.

Comment: @Matteo: C++/CLI is not C++, you know?

Comment: @Deduplicator: C++/CLI is a superset of C++ which allows mixing standard C++ with managed stuff. I see no harm in having both tags, given that (for example) many people who have some experience in C++/CLI (like me) do follow the C++ tag but not C++/CLI. Removing the C++ tag obsessively in search for purity IMO is just childish.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: C++/CLI is at best based on C++. Managed C++ in contrast tried (or succeeded?) in being a superset, though ultimately failed where it counts. Anyway, you are welcome to follow both tags, if you are interested in both.

Answer (score 7):

The string is neither stored on the stack or the heap.  The story is a bit convoluted.

The usually helpful way to think about it is that reference type objects are always stored on the GC heap.  Pretty similar to C++ (aka std::string), variable length objects like strings need to use the free store to allocate the correct amount of memory.  Modulo a possible micro-optimization in std::string that could store very short strings inside the std::string object.  But normally the std::string object itself can be allocated on the stack and the string *content* is allocated on the heap.  Just like `source` is on the stack, just a plain pointer that the garbage collector can find back.

The C language permits storing string content on the stack, but you have to guess the required string buffer length up front.  Launching thousands of malware attacks, string buffer overflows are a standard technique to mess with the program's stack frame and alter the function return value.  Not the .NET way.  A C language compiler doesn't *have* to do it that way, they just very commonly do.

But it is not straight-forward in the example you gave.  There is no difference between the statements, the string content is neither allocated on the stack nor the heap.  The CLR is heavily micro-optimized to take advantage of the CLI spec, the standard that describes how strings *must* behave in a conformant CLR implementation.

It takes advantage of the property that string objects are immutable.  That permits an optimization called *interning*.  The string object looks and behaves like it is stored on the GC heap.  But it actually isn't, the object content is directly read from the memory-mapped image of the assembly.  Stored in the "blob heap" in the assembly metadata.  The GC just ignores them when it encounters such a string object while it collects.  Pretty similar to how string literals behave in the C language.  Minus the bug that launched a billion crashes (a string literal is `char*` instead of `const char*` like it should be), you can never accidentally write to a string literal thanks to the immutability guarantee.

Comment: "It takes advantage of the property that string objects are immutable. That permits an optimization called interning." There's a second precondition, namely that equal strings may always be identical. It isn't mandatory, at least across assemblies, right? Nice post.

Comment: There is no guarantee whatsoever that identical strings have the same object address.  The CLR doesn't burn any cycles to try to find strings that could match a single interned string, this is sorted out at compile time.  Basic reason why canonical string literals like String.Empty are *readonly* instead of *const*.

Comment: The story gets even more convoluted if you consider that System::String is one of the two types in the CLR whose instances do not have a predetermined size.